# Which of these two laptops is better?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, gaming

I am planning to buy a gaming laptop and I have narrowed them down to these two laptops

[MSI GE62VR Apache Pro-001](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IO9Y3A6) - Price Around $1200 - $1300

[MSI GP62VR Leopard Pro-218](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M0COXDI) - Price Around $1100

I am sure that I need a gtx 1060, given how poor of choice it would be to take a 900 series gpu based laptop now. Also I need a 1080p laptop (since I need only a 15.6 inch screen and I feel that a higher resolution at this size is not that noticeable) itself, so going for a higher end gpu like a 1070 is probably overkill for a 1080p laptop.

The only major difference between them is the VRAM. For GE62VR there is a 6 GB VRAM for 1060 gpu, but for GP62VR there is only 3 GB VRAM and I read that the extra 3 GB is not that needed, at least for the next 3-4 years to come (correct me if I am wrong). Also one more thing that bugs me is the fact that there are no reviews about GP62VR, so I am not sure if it's a good laptop. However the GE62VR has many good reviews online, but the GP62VR is a bit cheaper.

So given the circumstances, and my current budget of about $1100 - $1300, which of these two laptops would you suggest?

P.S. On a side note, for my budget, would you suggest a different 1080p, GTX 1060 laptop altogether aside from these two?

Edit: 
I plan on using the laptop for gaming and maybe learning 3d modeling, game design etc in future, so I may run cinema 4d, blender, adobe products in future but only as a hobbyist or a beginner.

Comment: [GE62VR Review](http://www.gadgetreview.com/msi-ge62vr-apache-pro-gaming-laptop-review)    And [GP62VR Review](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/msi-gp62mvr-leopard-pro-gaming-laptop,4782.html)                      Not going to post as answer, but what is it you plan on using the laptop for?  gaming only? etc.

Comment: I have edited to add my plans for the usage of the laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that the GE62VR is a "better" laptop. All specifications on the two are equal with the exception of the following:

**Hard Drive:** GE62VR has an additional 256MB M.2 SSD
**Video Card:** GE62VR has an additional 3GB memory

Let's get into video memory. While you do need a good video card for the applications you are planning on using, the memory is not necessarily a benefit for you.

Video memory will help you with:

- Loading textures
- Holding the frame buffer
- Holding the depth buffer ("Z buffer")
- Holding other assets that are required to render a frame (shadow maps, etc.)

There is a great article at [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/graphics-card-myths,3694-5.html) on video memory.

In the end the GE62VR is a "better" laptop, but if you are not in need of the M.2 SSD then I'm not sure if the extra bit of VRAM will help you that much.

Answer (score 1):

For your listed purposes I would suggest the Apache Pro.

The SSD will speed up the loading of the OS, as well as editing programs installed to it, and the 16GB of ram will come in handy in media creation and 3D  modeling.